# Need formula to calculate value

Tags: math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Math - mapping numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345187/math-mapping-numbers)

I have value "x" that can be from 0 to 127 and a value "y" that can be from -1000 to 0.
I need to make that if x = 0 than y = -1000 and if x = 127 than y = 0... How can i make it?

Comment: What language? And which kind of function?

Comment: Are you using a programming language? Which?

Comment: what will be the value of y when x=1 or x=2 or x=4 ?

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345187/math-mapping-numbers

Comment: It's in C#, but i thought that was a simple mathematical expression, like the one sayed by Niki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just want a linear equation (y = mx + b).  In your case, this would be

```
y = x*(1000/127) - 1000
```

Comment: Depending on the language this might yield inaccurate results (if it takes the 1000 and 127 and does an integer divide). You might want to mention that.

Comment: And this is why modern programming courses don't have anywhere near enough math components :) (grumble grumble). Or enough onions on your belt.

Comment: @FBSC - you may want to check that... if you're using that directly, then the 1000/127 will evaluate to (int)7, whereas you want it to evaluate to about 7.87... See my answer for more information.

Comment: @Andrew i don't actually need that accuracy, since y is an integer, but i changed it :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

y = (x-127) * (1000/127)

Answer (score 1):

```
y = x * (1000.0/127.0) - 1000.0
```

Make sure you use float values in your calculation otherwise you will get inaccurate answers.

EDIT: And if you're really picky about accuracy, then this is better still:

```
y = (int) (0.5 + (x * (1000.0/127.0) - 1000.0))
```

(which will do correct rounding).

Answer (score 0):

linear interpolation...

slope = (0 - -1000) / (127 - 0) = (1000.0/127.0)
y-intercept = 127

y = (1000.0/127.0) * x - 1000

of course this assumes x and y can take on "real" values and not just integers.