# Very Simple Math Question

Tags: math

Very simple math question.

Say I have an image with a point being tracked in it. Here are my variables:

Image Height
Image Width
Point (pixles from left) coordinate X
Point (pixles from top) coordinate Y

For example the width, I want it to return a value of -0.5, which represents the distance from the center, such that 1 would be the total right, and -1 would be the total left.

So, how would I calculate so that

The point was (width) a quarter way across the entire frame, or a half way across the left SIDE of the frame. The variables would equal:

Image width: 40
Point X: 10

I know this is basic, but I seriously am having a mind cramp right now O_o.

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: Whatever you do, avoid dividing by zero. Assuming this problem is in relation to programming you are doing for the LHC, I do not wish for the universe to end just yet.

Comment: You need to clarify your coordinate systems. At one stage the width is in pixels (e.g. 40) and elsewhere in relative coordinates (-0.5). Also how can the width be -0.5 if the extent is -1 to +1. You need to be clear what your quantities are and then the answer may be clearer

Comment: I guess if you do a drawing, it'll be a lot easier to answer and perhaps you could realize better what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: check out [Math - mapping numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345187/math-mapping-numbers)

Comment: Dividing by zero = Black Hole

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Xnew = 2*X/Width - 1
Ynew = 2*Y/Height - 1
```

Explanation:

`X/Width` gives you value from 0 (total left) to 1 (total right). `2*X/Width` then gives a value from 0 (total left) to 2 (total right). Subtract 1 to get a value from -1 (total left) to 1 (total right).

The same for Y.

Comment: Thanks. I'm now ashamed I didn't think of that myself :P

Answer (score 1):

If image width is 40, and Point x is 10, then in "your" coordinates PointX will be 0.5 (assuming that coordinates are from -20 to 20). So:

```
PointX = 1 - 2 * (X / ImageWidth)
PointY = 1 - 2 * (Y / ImageHeight)
```

Checkout:

`PointX = 1 - 2 * (10 / 40) = 0.5` (or 10 pixels to the right side)