# Math - mapping numbers java

Tags: java, math

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345187/math-mapping-numbers) of mapping numbers algorithm.

I am trying to implement the @PeterAllenWebb solution in java like this:

```
long A = 1l;
long B =  999999999l;
long C = 1000000000l;
long D = 9999999999l;
long X =  999999998l;
long Y =   (D-C)*(X-A)/(B-A) + C;
System.out.println("original is " + X);     
long reverseX = (B-A)*(Y-C)/(D-C) + A;
System.out.println("reverse is " + reverseX);
```

However, this doesn't always work.

See below:

```
    X     reverseX
999999998 999999997
1         1
999999999 999999999
12        11
```

As you can see, only minimum (A) and maximum (B) are returning fine.

For the rest, I need to add 1. This seems to me as floor/round/Math issue and I don't want to rely on the JVM that calculates it. I would like it to always work.

How can I make the above work for reverseX?

Comment: So, what did you expect? It should have been `1`, since `(x - A)` == `1 - 1` == `0`. So, `Y = C`. And hence `reverseX = A`.

Comment: I would like x to be the original value! If I set x to 999999998, so this should be the result and not 999999997

Comment: I edited my question with different results

Comment: I think you would need to `round up` here.

Comment: Use `long reverseX = Math.round((B-A)*(Y-C)/(D-C) + 0.5) + A;`

Comment: doesn't work for x=999999999 the output is 1000000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing an age old issue. By default division is double in Java. So if your division result is 1.0 or 1.3 or 1.9 it will be truncated to 1. In your case the same is happening. Try changing it to double from long as below

```
double A = 1L;
double B = 999999999l;
double C = 1000000000l;
double D = 9999999999l;
double X = 999999998l;
double Y = (D - C) * (X - A) / (B - A) + C;

System.out.println("original is " + new DecimalFormat("#").format(X));
double reverseX = (B - A) * (Y - C) / (D - C) + A;
System.out.println("reverse is  "
        + new DecimalFormat("#").format(reverseX));
```

Comment: This doesn't work well. Since let's set String result = new DecimalFormat("#").format(Y); and then instead of double reverseX = (B - A) * (Y - C) / (D - C) + A; it will be double reverseX = (B - A) * (Double.praseDouble(result) - C) / (D - C) + A; it won't be accurate as format rounds the result. Your code works only if both are double